# Invalid JSON primitive:

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, javascriptserializer

I am new to using API and getting response from them using asp.net I am making a call to an API in my asp.net web application like this:

```
  public ActionResult MakeCall() {
            CallTRunkAPIResponse response = GET("https://apibetaus.calltrunk.com/api/v2/GetAccountSummarySimple?access_token=mytokenkeyhere");
            return Content("Make a call");
        }
```

I have created a method to get response, transfer the response to json format and then convert to my object type using javascript serializer  like this:

```
 public CallTRunkAPIResponse GET(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
        request.Headers.Add("X-Client:" + "header info from api here");
        request.Headers.Add("X-Authenticator-Session:" + "session key from api here");

        request.Method = "GET";

        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                //return reader.ReadToEnd();

                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                CallTRunkAPIResponse myojb = (CallTRunkAPIResponse)js.Deserialize(objText, typeof(CallTRunkAPIResponse));
                return myojb;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();

                // log errorText
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

}
```

My object is like this (dont know for below response what properties should i have in this response class:

```
 public class CallTRunkAPIResponse {

        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
    }
```

response should be like this but I get error:

```
{
"Status":"OK",
"Content":{
"Region":"beta.us",
"CurrencyCode":"USD",
"CurrencySymbol":"$",
"Languages":["en"],
"Version":{
"Api":{
"DisplayVersion":"2.0",
"Version":3},
"Client":{
"ReportedVersion":0,
"NewestVersion":2,
"MinVersion":2}
}
}
}
```

but I am getting this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: .
```

at:

```
 CallTRunkAPIResponse myojb = (CallTRunkAPIResponse)js.Deserialize(objText, typeof(CallTRunkAPIResponse));
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is most likely due to the fact that the service call has resulted in an exception getting thrown and the exception string is not a valid JSON object and hence it is not able to parse the response.

Check the following:

- Did the network call really succeed ? If it failed, chances are that the exception handling on the client is not good and you are trying to cast the exception object response into a JSON Object and hence the error message that you are seeing.
- The call did get through to the server and either there was an exception and / or the call resulted in an error message back to the client, which again is not a valid JSON Object and hence you cannot cast it to one.